# codeigniter css styles

Tags: css, codeigniter

The question is about using css stylesheets in your assets folder within the code igniter framework.  If I want to reference a certain image for a css style, lets say for instance, background: url('../images/some_image.gif').  How should I reference this image, and what url should I provide.  I'd like to do this in a way that I can put my image file in the image folder within assets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference in regards to this because you're using Codeigniter, you can use `/absolute/paths`, full URLs, or probably the easiest way - relative urls.

The url to the image can just be relative to the `<link>`ed CSS file.

Example:

> ```
> -assets
>    -css
>       screen.css
>    -images
>       bg.png
> ```

In your HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/screen.css">
```

From `screen.css`:

```
background:url(../images/bg.png);
```